# Rounding off numeric data while using SqlBulkCopy in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, oracle11g, sqlbulkcopy

I am using `SqlBulkCopy` to import data from Oracle 11g source to MS SQL Server 2012. But one of the `NUMERIC` columns in Oracle contains values like 53682.0(~35times)1, 263.9(~32times). The target column in Sql Server is currently a `FLOAT` datatype and currently I am getting the following Exception:

> *Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.*

This is my sample code:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(destConnString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            try
            {
                using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(srcConnString))
                {
                    using (OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(selectQuery, connection))
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                        using (OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.Default))
                        {
                            using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity, trans))
                            {
                                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = tableName;
                                bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 0;
                                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                trans.Commit();
            }
            ....
```

I am trying to round-off this data but with no success, also I cannot change anything in Oracle table.

Comment: Can you not change the column in your query?  In doing bulkcopy between SQL Server instances, I would just `CAST` the  field to the target data type in the query.

Comment: The range of values a float column will take is -1.79E+308 to -2.23E-308, 0 and 2.23E-308 to 1.79E+308. I doubt that the numeric column in Oracle is exceeding that range. I think this has to do with something besides the data types.

Comment: Does the data from Oracle arrive with commas, as you show in the value "1,263.9(~32times)"?

Comment: @Catcall No, they don't come with the commas, the comma above is used to seperate two sample numbers _53682.0(~35times)1_ and _263.9(~32times)_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just modify your Oracle SELECT query, e.g. to truncate the offending numeric value?

Comment: Thanks, that was indeed a simple solution, I didnot think of that ! :)